# Error while inserting image in table using Prawn

Tags: pdf, prawn

I am working with Prawn to generate a pdf, I have to insert an image in a cell of a table.

My code is like this:

```
image = "path to file"

subject = [["FORMATIVE I "," SUMATIVE ","GRAPH"],
           [formative_1,sumative, {:image => image}]
          ]
table subject
```

But, I get an error which says:

```
 prawn/table/cell.rb:127:in `make': Content type not recognized: nil (ArgumentError)
```

How can I resolve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: verdure, did you ever figure this out or find a way around it?

Answer (score 5):

In the current version of Prawn `0.12.0` it is not possible to embed images in a `Prawn::Table`, but this feature seems to be under way, see [here](https://github.com/sandal/prawn/issues/122). At the moment you have to write your own table, something like

```
data = [[{:image => "red.png"},{:text => "Red"}],
        [{:image => "blue.png"},{:text => "Blue"}]]
data.each_with_index do |row,i|
  row.each_with_index do |cell,j|
    bounding_box [x_pos,y_pos], :width => cell_width, :height => cell_height do
      image(cell[:image], ...) if cell[:image].present?
      text_box(cell[:text], ...) if cell[:text].present?
    end
    x_pos = (x_pos + cell_width)
  end
  y_pos = (y_pos - cell_height)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Prawn in version `0.12.0` doesn't give the possibility to insert image in a cell. Look at this for [further information](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/122). It works on the next version `1.0.0.rc1`. Just change your version. You can also use the tricky way, but I advise you not to do so.
The manual is available [here](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf).

The commit and explanation for that feature from the author. [Here](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/commit/7f06e94e)